# Mysql - How to Optimize Retrieval Time in a Table

Tags: mysql, index

I have query which has 200 million Records in a single table. I am using `BTree` indexes in my table:

```
mysql> select COUNT(DISTINCT id) from [tablename] where [columname] >=3;  
+------------------------------+  
| COUNT(DISTINCT id) |  
+------------------------------+  
|    8242063  
+------------------------------+  
1 row in set (3 min 23.53 sec)
```

I am not satisfy with this timing.

How can I reduce the result time less than 30sec. Kindly give me any suggessions! It will be more helpful to me!

Comment: You could use the explain keyword in front of your statement, you'll get a bit of information of what the query executes

Comment: is the id unique across the table? Why do you do 'COUNT(DISTINCT(id))' instead of 'COUNT(*)'?

Comment: I also tried Explain keyword.. which give only table rows count..

Comment: @newtover no, id is not unique in my table.. bcz of tat I m using distinct id

Comment: Can you add the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;` ?

Comment: @Zameer Are you still interested in this question?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `GROUP BY` can help. See this MySQL reference on [DISTINCT optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/distinct-optimization.html)

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
  SELECT 1
  FROM [tablename]
  WHERE [columnname] >= 3
  GROUP BY id
) q
```

Comment: The following query gives me individual counts of each id..  
I need whole table distince id count!
thank you!

Comment: Edited answer and wrapped in outer `SELECT`.

Comment: The given query was very helpful to me.. using this code I am getting the result within 1min.7sec.. thanks you!
Do u have any other idea to optimize further to get a result within 30sec..
thank in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an index on 'columnname' from the condition, and you really need 'COUNT(DISTINCT(id))', instead of just 'COUNT(*)' (that is the id is not UNIQUE or can be NULL), there is hardly anything you can do. What you request is basically an index scan starting from a given value '3', which is rather hard to express in other SQL terms.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using InnoDB engine you can try [partitions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html) over you column (list and range preferable to test).

Another option:

- add column `is_more_than_2`
- `is_more_than_2 = if(col > 2, 1, 0)`
- create index over this field and use it

But it will require some workaround to push this changes to production. Options:

- long downtime
- you can try do it without downtime but it will require a lot of workaround with additional table, triggers and replacing table at the end;

Hopes it helps

PS. Pure indexes will not helps you. Also you can think about re-implementing logic.

Answer (score -2):

Can you try the following?

```
select COUNT(id) from [tablename] where [columname] >=3 GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: What do you expect from this?